# Cordova 8.1.2 add platform issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a new cordova project. Cordova version is 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1).
I executed cordova create command and it correctly worked. Anyhow, when I execute the command

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~7.1.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

The Android SDK is installed, I do no longer know what to check... 
How can I detect if Android 7.1.1 (which cordova is trying to use) is installed on my PC?

Thanks for help!

Comment: you can try `cordova platform list`. What does it say?

Comment: Available platforms:
  android ~7.1.1
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~6.0.0

Comment: so it didn't install anything, was you internet connexion active when doing `cordova platform add android`? Try again with internet connection (and after having done `cd {yourFolderProject}` to be sure you are in your folder)

Comment: Yes, my Internet connection was active, and I checked I actually was in my project folder...

Comment: what is your cordova version? (add to the question itself in case it can help another user)

Comment: It is 8.1.2 version (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

The platform version is specified within the config.xml, you should find this line

```
<engine name="android" spec="YOUR_VERSION" />
```

Cordova will try to download the platform if not found locally.
If the problem is not related with connection you could try to update the platform spec, try the follow

```
<engine name="android" spec="^7.1.1" />
```

If the problem persist you can eventually update the version in use

```
<engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
```

Then retry platform add

EDIT

Try to add the platform with a specified version

```
cordova platform add android@7.1.4
```

If there are some other issue you should try to follow the official doc for creating a project with cordova cli

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/guide/cli/index.html

Comment: Is config.xml inside project folder?

Comment: Yes, in the project root directory, at the same level of the src directory

Comment: @SergioRinaudo the engine tag will not be there if there is no platform installed..

Comment: I've edited my answer, try to specify which version when add. If error persist try to create a new project with cordova cli. If you have any other issues post the error message

Comment: I've tried both to create a new project and add a specific version. Anyhow, the error message is always the same...

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: The last thing I can say that is a permission problem: several times ENOENT error is related to that, if under linux try the command with sudo. 
If persist I really can't do anything because I've personally tried minutes ago all the advices given in this answer :/

Comment: I solved the problem uninstalling and then re-installing Cordova. I definitely don't know what was wrong... Thank you everybody